# The origin of superhuman speed in Cyberpunk 2077

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

When I play Cyberpunk 2077, I find some NPCs have superhuman speed. I know it may be related to body modification, but I don't know the whole backstory. Is there any canon info on it?

Comment: Sounds like you are talking about the enemies doing some small "teleport" like movements of only a couple of meters? These generally have Sandevistan and Kereznikov, I guess that's what it looks like when seen from outside.

Answer (score 9):

### Superspeed Glitches are not intended gameplay nor supported canonically in-game

**Superspeed Glitches**

> One glitch in question involves [modding up V with Maneuvering System](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.polygon.com/platform/amp/2021/1/5/22215647/cyberpunk-speed-glitch-dash-bug-maneuvering-system), a piece of cyberware that lets the player execute a dodge mid-air:
> Find said cyberware in Santo Domingo’s Arroyo sub-district. This cyberware also allows players to dash mid-air. When a mid-air dash is properly timed, it gives V super-speed.
> Other players have found ways to compound the gains with in-world mods, like reinforced tendons (available at the ripperdoc in Watson, Little China), which adds a double-jump to the player’s repertoire.

Another method is though the [Kerenzikov mod](https://indiefaq.com/guides/cyberpunk-2077-kerenzikov-dodge-speed-glitch.html), found at most ripper docs for 1000 eurodollars:

> Once you have entered slow motion press your C key as fast as possible. This initiates multiple slides within the span of an in game second which is released all at once upon exiting slow motion. When the slow motion nears its end and the screen begins to zoom out you will want to jump. Jumping will ensure you maintain your momentum as the only force that can stop you now is friction a brick wall and if you’re lucky enough maybe a truck.

### NPC In-Game AI & Powers have been tweaked multiple times since launch — it’s partly been a gameplay design problem

NPC police abilities were a notable “broken” feature of the game at launch, which was toned down [with Patch 1.2](https://www.cyberpunk.net/en/news/37801/patch-1-2-list-of-changes). The launch version had cops being able to spawn on foot at location where player commits crimes, in large numbers, and had ability to move quickly to the player. Many players and reviewers troubleshooted this gameplay and divined that was simply how cops were handled: there was no “witness” type system of other similar games; commit a crime and cops spawned in without any canon explanation as if by magic. As this was a frequent complaint, the devs have been tweaking cop powers and AI since launch via patches; for example [Patch 1.21](https://www.cyberpunk.net/en/news/37984/hotfix-1-21) additionally tweaked these same issues.

[Patch 1.2](https://www.cyberpunk.net/en/news/37801/patch-1-2-list-of-changes)

[Patch 1.21](https://www.cyberpunk.net/en/news/37984/hotfix-1-21)

### “No Pushovers” — In Any Case, NCPD is Canonically Augmented as Confirmed by CD Projekt Red

Level Designer Miles Tost [confirms NCPD are augmented](https://gamingbolt.com/cyberpunk-2077-police-wont-be-pushovers-side-missions-are-interwoven-with-the-main-story) with cyberware to make them difficult:

> The world will also feel completely alive, with the player feeling like a part of it—which, after all, they, as V, are. For instance, Tost explained how the police in the game might respond to any lawbreaking done by the player.
>
> > “It’s really important to us to portray a world that you feel a part of, so naturally, the world also has to react to your presence,” he said. “Regarding this particular example, let me just say the Night City police don’t react lightly to people stepping out of the line. **Their cyber implants**, as well as advanced weaponry make them not a pushover, either.”

### Yep, NCPD must be…

With their initial inability to spawn if you’re looking in their direction, and an ability to super-speed spawn in behind your back where you’re not looking, the only reasonable explanation is that NCPD hires Weeping Angels.

Comment: I'm not talking about bugs or mods for the game. The cops, for example, can move very fast when they are in high alert. They can close in on you in less than a second.

Comment: A good answer, but lacking in references.

Comment: When I first played the game, it's 1.23 already. The cops and some elite NPCs can still move like a ghost.